# How can I remove None from the last line of output in python

Tags: python

CODE:

```
import textwrap

def wrap(string, max_width):
    m=0
    x=[]
    wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=max_width)
    word_list = wrapper.wrap(text=string)
    for element in word_list:
        print(element)
        
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    string, max_width = input(), int(input())
    result = wrap(string, max_width)
    print(result)
```

INPUT:

```
abcdef
2
```

OUTPUT:

```
ab
cd
ef
None
```

I want ouput as it is but want to remove "None" from last lime.
I used python 3.8.3
Please somenone help me .. it will be great help

Comment: You can just filter out the list: `list(filter(lambda x: x, result))`

Answer (score 0):

You use this, list compreheison that will ignore None values

```
word_list = [x for x in wrapper.wrap(text=string) if x]
```

Answer (score 0):

print() function returns a None Object. So instead of

```
result = wrap(string, max_width)
print(result)
```

Write directly -

```
wrap(string, max_width)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `wrap` function doesn't return any values, so when you write,

```
result = wrap(string, max_width)
```

the Python interpreter assigns the value `None` to the variable `result`. It doesn't have any value to assign.

Besides that, you are trying to print your wrapped text twice. Once inside the `wrap` function and once outside of it.

Either rewrite `wrap` as,

```
def wrap(string, max_width):
    wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=max_width)
    word_list = wrapper.wrap(text=string)
    return "\n".join(word_list)
```

or (as PCM suggested) change your main to,

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    string, max_width = input(), int(input())
    wrap(string, max_width)
```

depending on the behavior you want.

If you're not familiar, `"\n".join(word_list)` will turn the list into a string joined with newline characters. [(documentation of str.join)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

You also have two unused variables at the start of `wrap` you should probably get rid of.